# what different between WeakReference and SoftReference

Tags: android, dalvik

I find the document on this [link](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/ref/WeakReference.html)
It describe as below:

Weak references are useful for mappings that should have their entries removed automatically once they are not referenced any more (from outside). The difference between a SoftReference and a WeakReference is the point of time at which the decision is made to clear and enqueue the reference:
A SoftReference should be cleared and enqueued as late as possible, that is, in case the VM is in danger of running out of memory.
A WeakReference may be cleared and enqueued as soon as is known to be weakly-referenced.

But when I look through the Dalvikvm's source code, found something in dvmCollectGarbageInternal(Heap.cpp L446 Android 4.4) function. It seem two references are 
cleared at the same time.

```
 /*
 * All strongly-reachable objects have now been marked.  Process
 * weakly-reachable objects discovered while tracing.
 */
dvmHeapProcessReferences(&gcHeap->softReferences,
                         spec->doPreserve == false,
                         &gcHeap->weakReferences,
                         &gcHeap->finalizerReferences,
                         &gcHeap->phantomReferences);
```

Do I miss something?

================================================================================

With @fadden's help, I found the reserve code

```
if (!marked && ((++counter) & 1))
```

The dalvikvm reserve the half sofereference every GC procedure, and I copy someone's test code the test

final ArrayList> list = new ArrayList>(
                SR_COUNT);
        for (int i = 0; i < SR_COUNT; ++i) {
            list.add(new SoftReference(new Integer(i)));
        }

```
    /* Test */
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; ++i) {
        System.gc();

        try {
            Thread.sleep(200);
        } catch (final InterruptedException e) {
        }
    }

    /* Check */
    int dead = 0;
    for (final SoftReference<Integer> ref : list) {
        if (ref.get() == null) {
            ++dead;
        }
        Log.d(TAG, "dead: " + dead);
    }
```

All the log from logcat is just what I think.

Answer (score 3):

FWIW, the best description of weak/soft/phantom references in Java is in chapter 17 of *The Java Programming Language* ("Garbage Collection and Memory").

There's no mandated policy for soft reference retention.  The VM is allowed to discard all or none during a GC, or anything in between.  The only requirement is that the VM is supposed to discard all softly-reachable objects before throwing OOM.

You can continue Dalvik's logic in `dvmHeapProcessReferences()` in [MarkSweep.cpp](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/dalvik/+/kitkat-release/vm/alloc/MarkSweep.cpp).  Note in particular the call to `preserveSomeSoftReferences()`, which retains some but not others based on the reference "color".  You can read more about colors on the [wikipedia GC article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Garbage_collection_%28computer_science%29).

Comment: Your are right. I found the reserve code  "if (!marked && ((++counter) & 1))" 。 The dalvikvm reserve the half sofereference every GC procedure

Comment: Yup.  Every GC you lose half your soft references regardless of the state of the system.  Not very useful for app developers.

Comment: But why?Why not use FILO,I think that would be better for program to keep what it need

Comment: I agree.  The engineers responsible for the Dalvik GC felt otherwise.

Answer (score 1):

From Understanding Weak References, by Ethan Nicholas: 
https://weblogs.java.net/blog/enicholas/archive/2006/05/understanding_w.html

Weak references

A weak reference, simply put, is a reference that isn't strong enough to force an object to remain in memory. Weak references allow you to leverage the garbage collector's ability to determine reachability for you, so you don't have to do it yourself. You create a weak reference like this:

WeakReference weakWidget = new WeakReference(widget);

and then elsewhere in the code you can use weakWidget.get() to get the actual Widget object. Of course the weak reference isn't strong enough to prevent garbage collection, so you may find (if there are no strong references to the widget) that weakWidget.get() suddenly starts returning null.

...

Soft references

A soft reference is exactly like a weak reference, except that it is less eager to throw away the object to which it refers. An object which is only weakly reachable (the strongest references to it are WeakReferences) will be discarded at the next garbage collection cycle, but an object which is softly reachable will generally stick around for a while.

SoftReferences aren't required to behave any differently than WeakReferences, but in practice softly reachable objects are generally retained as long as memory is in plentiful supply. This makes them an excellent foundation for a cache, such as the image cache described above, since you can let the garbage collector worry about both how reachable the objects are (a strongly reachable object will never be removed from the cache) and how badly it needs the memory they are consuming.

And Peter Kessler added in the comments:

The Sun JRE does treat SoftReferences differently from WeakReferences. We attempt to hold on to object referenced by a SoftReference if there isn't pressure on the available memory. One detail: the policy for the "-client" and "-server" JRE's are different: the -client JRE tries to keep your footprint small by preferring to clear SoftReferences rather than expand the heap, whereas the -server JRE tries to keep your performance high by preferring to expand the heap (if possible) rather than clear SoftReferences. One size does not fit all.